# In Redshift how do assign value of a column to a variable

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

When running the below the value in the out variable is always null and I want to be able to return a single value of a column from a single row from the stored procedure. Trying to write a wrapper that inserts a row if doesnt exist against a table which has a primary key that is autogenerated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE api.some_proc(v_input IN varchar(100), v_output OUT int)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    
DECLARE
    cnt int;
begin   
    Select into v_output max(col_name) from (select col_name from table_name where ...)
END;

$$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using `RECORD` and a for loop like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE api.some_proc(v_inIN varchar(100), v_output OUT int)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    
DECLARE
    records RECORD;
begin   
    FOR records IN select col_name from table_name where ...
      LOOP
       v_output = records.col_name;
    END LOOP;
    
END;

$$
;
```